REST API OAuth - Can we directly login without Consumer key and secret
We are using Magento EE 1.14 code.
Requirement :
We Need to create an REST API OAuth direct login extension to make the login. that only require username and password (without need the consumer key and secret), create a sample REST API server and client code to demonstrate retrieving customer info.
$callbackUrl = "http://test.php";
$temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl = "http://oauth/initiate?oauth_callback=" . urlencode($callbackUrl);
$adminAuthorizationUrl = 'http://admin/oauth_authorize'; //this is what you need.
$accessTokenRequestUrl = 'http://oauth/token';
$apiUrl = 'http://api/rest';

Is above the correct code ?
Update
By default the magento 1.x provides REST API, but during the user authorization, user is asked to input username and password on the web page to grant access, what we need is REST API OAuth direct login to bypass this step, extend the authorize REST API and pass in the username and password as additional input to gain access, so the authentication process will be just REST API call without need to go through the web page to grant access.
